# Blender Game Python при изменении меша нормали не обновляются

Tags: python, разработка-игр, blender

При изменении меша через python в игре (через bge, а не bpy) нормали не обновляются: [image: пример:]

Из-за этого освещение рассчитывается как для плоскости. Версии Blender 2.69, 2.76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно пересчитать нормали. Я не нашел функцию, которая это делает, поэтому нашел [наработки в сети](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?409118-How-to-calculate-vertex-normal).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код пересчета нормалей:

```
for poly_id in range(mesh.numPolygons):
        poly = mesh.getPolygon(poly_id)
        v1 = mesh.getVertex(mat_id, poly.v1)
        v2 = mesh.getVertex(mat_id, poly.v2)
        v3 = mesh.getVertex(mat_id, poly.v3)
        if poly.v4 == 0:
            normal = mathutils.geometry.normal(v1.getXYZ(), v2.getXYZ(), v3.getXYZ())
            v1.setNormal(normal)
            v2.setNormal(normal)
            v3.setNormal(normal)
        else:
            v4 = mesh.getVertex(mat_id, poly.v4)
            normal = mathutils.geometry.normal(v1.getXYZ(), v2.getXYZ(), v3.getXYZ(), v4.getXYZ())
            v1.setNormal(normal)
            v2.setNormal(normal)
            v3.setNormal(normal)
            v4.setNormal(normal)
```